# How to assign an hostname to an Azure Application Gateway with AGIC

Tags: azure, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, azure-application-gateway

I'm using the Azure Kubernetes Service to deploy a web application on k8s and I'm using the [Application Gateway Ingress Controller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-overview) to forward the requests from the outside of the k8s cluster.

I defined the Ingress in this way:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-path-prefix: /
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-private-ip: "true"
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - my.hostname.com
    secretName: my-cert
  rules:
  - host: my.hostname.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: my-backend
          servicePort: 80
```

`my-cert` is a secret I created that contains a SSL certificate my company bought some time ago that is valid for all the names `*.hostname.com` (is an example).

Now, if I apply this YAML the AGIC gets configured with the secret (I can see from the AGIC's pod logs that everything is fine) but I cannot access my application at the URL `my.hostname.com`, neither via HTTP nor via HTTPS.

If, instead, I drop the line `host: my.hostname.com` from the Ingress definition I can access the application via the Application Gateway's private IP.

Do you know if I have to perform some special operations to assign the hostname to my Application Gateway when using AGIC?

Comment: As far as I checked [here](https://azure.github.io/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/tutorials/tutorial.general/#with-specified-hostname) your `- hosts` should have 2 more indentations, could you try to add it and test again?

Comment: @Jakub I don't think it's a formatting problem because the kubectl checks the format and warns in case of errors. Anyway I found the solution (and I put the answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the problem/solution. I only had to assign the `my.hostname.com` hostname to the private network's IP in the company Domain Controller. This way in the company network the hostname is resolvable to the IP